# Linear Algebra True or False Questions.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have some problems determining why these statements are true would someone if they be willing help me with some of these?

[image]

Now I know the definition of a column space it is the set col A of all linear combination of columns of A. I just do not understand how this applies here. Moreover I do not know what the codomain signifies? Linear subspace $R^n$ I knew this and that it is contained in another space but are we talking about dimensions of range and codmain? I know 3 is false because this will change the answer . Four is true because of the 3 elementary rules interchange, replace,scale. I do not understand 5 so well. Any hints on proving whether this is true or false would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) $col(A)$ is the set of all linear combinations of n m-dimensional vectors. When $n < m$, we cannot have that $col(A) = \mathbb{R}^m$, since you must have at least m m-dimensional vectors to span $\mathbb{R}^m$. So this is not true.

(2) For a vector space V to be a subspace of another vector space W, there are certain properties that V and W must satisfy. One such property is that $V \subseteq W$. Clearly, $\mathbb{R}^2 \not\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$, since any element of $\mathbb{R}^2$ cannot be in $\mathbb{R}^3$. So this is false.

(5) There is a famous theorem called rank-nullity, which says that if $A$ is $m \times n$, then $rank(A) + nullity(A) = n$ (nullity is the dimension of the null space). The rank of $A$ is equal to the pivot columns. So then the number of non-pivot columns is equal to $n - rank(A) = nullity(A)$. So this is true.